# What time complexity does my print triangle algorithm have?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What time complexity does my print triangle algorithm have?

```
void print(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return;
    for (int k = n; k > 0; k--) {
        out.printf("[*]");
    }
    out.println();
    print(--n);
}
```

I think it's `O(n^2)`, because we go through all columns and rows. Am I right? However, I have some doubts about recursion impact on the algorithm.

Comment: You are Right the complexity is Big-O of N^2.

Answer (score 1):

The first iteration has *n* steps, the second *n* - 1, and so on down to 1.  As you recall, the sum of the series {1, 2, …, *n*} is (*n*<sup>2</sup> + *n*)/2.  (The proof is a standard introduction to the concept of induction.)  This is indeed O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).